# Understanding do-while loop

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm doing the oracle certified associate Java SE7 Programmer practice exams (the book) and came across a question, and I don't understand the answer even with the explanation.
Here's the explanation and the code:

> It will print 3. The loop body is executed twice and the program will print 3.

I don't understand how the loop body is executed twice, maybe I don't understand what the `b=!b` means. Can someone explain please?

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        boolean b = false;
        int i = 1;
        do{
            i + + ;
        } while (b = !b);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm, that looks like an infinite loop to me. b=!b means negate b (true) and set b to it (true).

Comment: oh ok, that's what I thought

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that down right, that looks like the loop should never exit. `b` is never being changed. That is bizarre.

Comment: yea, how can i post a screenshot?

Comment: I just tested it, and it does indeed print 3...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b = !b` is an ***assignment*** which assigns the inverse of b to itself (effectively flipping between true and false)

in java, an assignment returns what was assigned (so that `a=b=1` is possible)

therefore `while (b=!b)` will flip the value of b, and then check the value of b.

Comment: so first it says *assign "true" to the value of b (since it was false first), then check, if it's true stay in loop, and then goes into second iteration and assigns false, and checks, and since it's false it exits the loop this time?

Answer (score 1):

```
b=!b
```

Will always be true, why?
Because, what you are doing is that you insert to "b" the opposite value (T->F, F->T),and if there was no problem `while (b = !b);` will return TRUE....
So at your case `while (b = !b);` will always return true

Comment: Nice catch. So what is happening is that it works the first time because it is a do loop, and then runs again before the condition becomes false.

Comment: The condition will never be false, because as same as you do `b=false` - "FALSE" was enter to `b`, and yes, this is true that this is what happened...

Comment: Think about like this: If you write `b==FALSE` the you asking the compiler if "b" have the value "false", if yes - the compiler will answer you with "TURE". When you write something like `b=!b` you say to the compiler - Answer TRUE the action pass right, i.e. 'b' gets the opposite value, and yes, no matter what 'b' gets the opposite value...

Answer (score 1):

**Iteration 1**

```
boolean b = false; 
int i = 1; 
do{ 
    i++ ; // i = 2
} while (b = !b); // b = !false = true so one more execution
```

**Iteration 2**

```
do{ 
    i++ ; // i = 3
} while (b = !b); // b = !true = false so loop breaks
```

So it will print `3`. simple :)

Actually the confusion is with `=` sign. `=` is assigning operator where as `==` is the conditional operator. The first will assign the value whereas later will check for the condition. You can play with it and have some other result like

```
int a = 6;
int b = 10;
System.out.println(a = b);
System.out.println(a == b);
```

and you will get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the first iteration the variable `i` will be `2` because of the increment operator. The expression `b=!b` will result to `true` (`b = !false`) and set the variable `b` to `true` as well. So the loop gets executed again.

At the end of the second iteration the variable `i` is now `3`. The expression `b=!b` will result to `false` (`b = !true`), which will be also the value of the variable `b`. So the whole do-while-loop terminates and the `println()` statement shows `3`.

Keep in mind: `=` (assign operator) is not the same as `==` (equality check).

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
b = !b;
```

uses the *assignment* operator, which returns the value that has been assigned.

Initially, `b` is false, and therefore `true` is assigned to `b`, and used for the condition. The while loop therefore executes a second time. In this execution, `b` is true, and therefore `false` is assigned to `b` and used for the loop condition. The loop therefore exits.